# fancyvrb dynamic label

Tags: fancyvrb

I load multiple source files into a document using the `fancyvrb` package. I found out how to include a static label. Now, I want to display the filename in the label (dynamic label based on input file). How can I achieve this?

In the following example, the label should be `file_1.txt` and `file_2.txt` instead of `data.txt`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\RecustomVerbatimCommand{\VerbatimInput}{VerbatimInput}{
    label=\fbox{data.txt},
    labelposition=topline,
}

\begin{document}

\VerbatimInput{file_1.txt}
\VerbatimInput{file_2.txt}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd avoid redefining `\VerbatimInput`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newcommand{\verbatiminput}[1]{%
  \VerbatimInput[
    label=\fbox{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}},
    labelposition=topline,
    frame=single,
  ]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\verbatiminput{file_1.txt}

\verbatiminput{file_2.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]